# Word for relative/proprietary beliefs?

Tags: single-word-requests

What other word would be suitable to describe one's *relative/proprietary* beliefs?

i.e. Something that an individual decided should be morally good. e.g., if one had the belief that every car should be painted green. Something not rooted in a moral framework.

The word I've heard but cannot recall starts with either an ar- or an re-. Thank you!

Comment: What's a "relative/proprietary belief"?

Comment: @WeatherVane Something that an individual decided should be morally good. e.g., if one had the belief that every car should be painted green. Something not rooted in a moral framework.

Comment: That's not a belief. A belief is when someone thinks every car **is** painted green.

Comment: @WeatherVane In the context of morality, somebody may believe -- as many religions do -- that lying is wrong. Not lying is the correct way for one to behave. They do not believe that nobody lies.

Comment: @Human: You need to define "relative/proprietary belief" ***in the question text itself***, or your question is likely to be closed as "Unclear what you're asking".

Comment: It would also be helpful for readers to have a clear definition and example of this because I think many people might not be familiar with this term.

Comment: 'Something that an individual [(X)] decided should be morally good. e.g., if one had the belief that every car should be painted green. Something not rooted in a moral framework.' >> This is a contradiction: obviously the belief is part of _**X**_'s moral framework. // Firstly, there needs to be a statement about whether the question assumes moral absolutism or moral universalism (or neither) [[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moral_absolutism)]

Comment: Isn’t that a ***personal*** belief?

Comment: perhaps this is merely a preference.

Comment: I wonder if you're thinking of "dispositional beliefs". But if so, I think the "*morally* good" is confusing.

Comment: In addition to the problems that have been pointed out above, it is rather unclear what the word *proprietary* is doing here. What is supposed to be whose **property** here?

Answer (score 0):

If an individual decides that something should be morally good, that's a moral framework by its very definition. It's perfectly possible to have a moral framework that only *you* subscribe to.

However, I believe the word you're looking for is [**relativism**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/relativism):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **1 b** : a view that ethical truths depend on the individuals and groups holding them